# php convert time period into number

Tags: php

i have a database which compare birthdate of a person to current date to get age of the person at given time.

i use the following code to convert them into age

```
$datetime_date = date("d-m-Y");

$time_diff = abs(strtotime($datetime_date) - strtotime($birthdate));

$years = floor($time_diff / (365*60*60*24));

$months = floor(($time_diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));

$days = floor(($time_diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

if ($years > 0) {$new_age = "$years year $months month";}

elseif (($years == 0) && ($months > 0)) {$new_age = "$months month $days day";}

elseif (($years == 0) && ($months == 0)) {$new_age = "$days day of life";}
```

i have saved the age in the database as:
(number) year (number) month OR
(number) month (number) days OR
(number) days

currently, i would like to group them into agegroup, so i would need to convert them back into numbers for comparison

eg: 
group age < 1 year
group age 1-12 years
group age 12-60 year etc

can someone advice how to convert a age (in time period) back into numberical format or unix format for easy comparison?

Comment: also note that i realise i can store the $time_diff in database and use it for comparison. I plan to use it in the future. 

however, i already have a lot of data in the above mention time period format and looking for a way for the system to re-convert them into timestring

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the fields back to seconds

```
$new_age_split = explode(" ",$new_age);

if ($new_age_split[1] == 'year')
{
$age = (($new_age_split[0] * 365) + ($new_age_split[2] * 30) + $new_age_split[4]) * 24*60*60
}
else
{
if ($new_age_split[1] == 'month')
{
$age = (($new_age_split[0] * 30) + $new_age_split[2] ) * 24*60*60
}
else
if ($new_age_split[1] == 'day')
{
$age = ($new_age_split[0]) * 24*60*60
}
```

Then you can use the `new DateTime(date("U") - $age)` or `date_create(date("U") - $age)` depending on what you need to do with the output

Comment: it is true, but the data now is in varchar format eg:"3 year 4 month". of course i could parse the string by subs number before the word "year" and between the word "year" & "month" for number of month.

however, this is rather tedious. I wonder if there are easier method?

Comment: I have updated answer.. but you may need to remove the days from the first if statement `new_age_split[4]` as it doesnt look like you save that information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes; they make your task easier:

```
$birthdate = new DateTime('1997-09-14');
$today     = new DateTime('now');
$diff = $today->diff($birthdate);

echo('Age: '.$diff->y."\n");
print_r($diff);
```